# Lock the page scroll when modal window opened

Tags: javascript, scroll

How do I stop scrolling when a modal window is opened

I call the modal window in so many places that the window is calling some other function. At the time the modal window appears the page scrolls creates a problem going up.

I want to fix the position of scrolling when modal window is called or any modal window function is called.

So basically I wrote one scroll event to control the scrolling but it is going up only. I want to be fixed the position of scroll bar in same when its called the modal window.

```
 document.body.scrollTop     = 0;
```

Comment: You should add your code sample, perhaps a jsfiddle or similar.

Answer (score 0):

Check if your modal adds any class to body element. If so, just apply `overflow: hidden` to this class. Else, when opening modal, add some class to body element manually and apply same overflow.

Comment: but in this case of overflow:hidden only hiding the scroll bar not its functioning.i need something that lock the parnent window scroll bar position when modal window opened

Comment: @user3804435 with overflow property, you remove scrolling function too. http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/playit.asp?filename=playcss_overflow&preval=hidden